# Make prolonged text suffix with ... under grid display

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

Given the css

```
   .table {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 170px 170px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .tr {
      display: contents;
    }
    .td {
      display: flex;
      border-left: 1px solid black;
      border-rigth: 1px solid black;
    }
    div {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

And JSX

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="table">
      <div className="tr">
        <div className="td">
          abcsfsaffadsfsdfsafsdsfsadfdasdfasfasdffasfasfasdfsd
        </div>
        <div className="td">abcasfsdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

See [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-alex-tiewtu?file=/src/App.js)

The text from left column overlaps the right.

Is there a way to make first column appears "..." at the end of prolonged text, so that it won't overlapped?
Assume the line `grid-template-columns: 170px 170px;` can't be changed in css

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: ^remove display:flex and add `overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Answer (score 0):

A simple change is if you add the following to your CSS within `div` or `.td`.

```css
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Also remove.

```css
      display: flex;
```

Comment: Doh. Should've posted sooner instead of eating dinner  The above comment from Temani Afif is the same answer.